# How to print the last but one record of a file using awk?

Tags: unix

How to print the last but one record of a file using awk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
awk '{ prev_line=this_line; this_line=$0 } END { print prev_line }' < file
```

Essentially, keep a record of the line before the current one, until you hit the end of the file, then print the previous line.

*edit to respond to comment:*

To just extract the second field in the penultimate line:

```
awk '{ prev_f2=this_f2; this_f2=$2 } END { print prev_f2 }' < file
```

Comment: @Raje - I edited the answer to make it a little clearer; they are awk variables.

Comment: if we want to print the second field of that line?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `awk` but you may find that:

```
tail -2 inputfile | head -1
```

will be a quicker solution - it grabs the last two lines of the complete set then the first of those two.

The following transcript shows how this works:

```
pax$ echo '1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5' | tail -2 | head -1
4
```

If you *must* use `awk`, you can use:

```
pax$ echo '1
2
3
4
5' | awk '{last = this; this = $0} END {print last}'
4
```

It works by keeping the last and current line in variables `last` and `this` and just printing out `last` when the file is finished.